# If I pass a JWT in the URL does this mean it isn't being stored?

Tags: jwt

I know that JWTs can be stored through a series of different methods, but hypothetically speaking if I sent a JWT like so `https://www.website.com?access_token=<JWT>` does this mean it isn't being stored? If it is being stored how can I tell the method in which it is being stored.